# ¿como restar 4 horas a mi fecha actual?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Usé TIMESTAMP pero no resta nada sigue igual

```
consulta_product= ("""
                SELECT display_name,date_approve,price_unit FROM purchase_order_line pol
                join purchase_order po on po.id = pol.order_id
                join res_partner rp on po.partner_id = rp.id WHERE pol.product_id = """ + str(produ[1]) + """
                and (po.date_approve::TIMESTAMP+ '-4 hr')::date >= '"""+str(data['form']['start_date'])+ """'
                AND (po.date_approve::TIMESTAMP+ '-4 hr')::date <= '"""+str(data['form']['end_date'])+ """'
                """)
```

Comment: uso postgresql, como lo resulevo ?

Answer (score 0):

En [este enlace](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL) (en inglés, me temo) puedes encontrar más información sobre como realizar operaciones sobre los campos de tipos asociados a dates y times.

Sería interesante que facilitaras la estructura básica de tus tablas (sentencias create) y un juego de datos mínimo (sentencias insert) para poder reproducir y probar.

Dado que no disponemos de esa información, he creado esto para

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE purchase_order  (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    date_approve TIMESTAMP NOT NULL    
);

INSERT INTO purchase_order (id, date_approve) VALUES (1, timestamp '2015-01-11 00:51:14');
INSERT INTO purchase_order (id, date_approve) VALUES (2, timestamp '2016-01-11 00:51:14');
INSERT INTO purchase_order (id, date_approve) VALUES (3, timestamp '2017-01-11 00:51:14');
INSERT INTO purchase_order (id, date_approve) VALUES (4, timestamp '2018-01-11 00:51:14');
INSERT INTO purchase_order (id, date_approve) VALUES (5, timestamp '2019-01-11 00:51:14');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT id, date_approve - INTERVAL '1 month' as modified_date FROM purchase_order;
```

| id | modified_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2014-12-11T00:51:14.000Z |
| 2 | 2015-12-11T00:51:14.000Z |
| 3 | 2016-12-11T00:51:14.000Z |
| 4 | 2017-12-11T00:51:14.000Z |
| 5 | 2018-12-11T00:51:14.000Z |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/36NTMCe6h3KK6Z8ckpLWND/0)

No sé de qué tipo has declarado el campo date_approve, pero si ya es un TIMESTAMP no tendrías que añadir ::TIMESTAMP, es redundante. A priori y con los pocos datos que aportas bastaría sustituir

> po.date_approve::TIMESTAMP+ '-4 hr'

por

> po.date_approve - INTERVAL '4 hour'

Answer (score 0):

De manera puntual no funciona la resta porque después de eso le haces una conversión al tipo date que elimina las horas dejando solo la fecha.

(po.date_approve::TIMESTAMP+ '-4 hr')::date <- esta conversión está de más

(po.date_approve::TIMESTAMP+ '-4 hr')